# How to Jasmine test an async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jasmine

I'm terrible at async in general. I've read all the other answers, but they haven't helped me to understand this. This the code I'm trying to test:

```
$("#do").click(function() {
  someFunction().then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      failureFunction(result.error_message)
    } else {
      successFunction(result.token)
    }
  })
})
```

`someFunction()` is an async function that will return either `{error: true, error_message: "failed due to error"}` or `{token:"success token"}`.

I'd like to test that both branches work, i.e., that `failureFunction` and `successFunction` are called appropriately with the right arguments.

Here's my Jasmine so far:

```
describe("calling someFunction", function() {
  describe("when result is good", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn(window, "successFunction")
      response = Promise.resolve({token: "asdf"});
      spyOn(window, "someFunction").and.returnValue(response)
      $("#do").trigger("click")
    })
    it("should call successsFunction appropriately", function(){
      expect(window.successFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith("asdf")
    })
  })
  // ... once I get above to pass it's just emulating with failureFunction
})
```

The error I get when run:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

So I'm guessing that the stubbed `returnValue` of `someFunction` (which is `response`) is not a promise object on which `.then` can be called... but this seems right to me?

Comment: What is the error? Your code as it looks, should works. **Notice**: you have a syntax error in  `response = Promise.resolve({token: "asdf");`, you are missing the closing `}`

Comment: @CastroRoy yes thanks for that edit. I posted the error

Comment: In which line you get that error? Calling `Promise.resolve({token: "asdf"})` returns a resolved promise on which you can call `.then` AFAIK. Again, _your code as it looks, should works_ :-).

Comment: yup you're right... unrelated issue. doh!

Comment: @CastroRoy any chance you can help on this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53568192/how-to-test-done-part-of-ajax-in-jasmine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the expectation in the `it` was running BEFORE the async function that I mocked had finished resolving. So the solution is to wrap the expectations themselves in an analogous `.then`. This worked:

```
it("should call successsFunction appropriately", function(){
  response.then(function() {
    expect(window.successFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith("asdf")
  })
})
```